# OWIN Middleware: find if the request has a matched route

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-web-api-routing, owin-middleware

We would like to write a piece of OWIN middleware that looks at the current request and see if it matches any mapped routes (we are using web.api, so we register routes with the `httpRouteCollection.MapHttpRoute` method.

If the current request does not match any known configured routes we would like to reject it with a custom 404 message.

Is it possible to determine from the OWIN context whether the current request matches one of the defined routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, no, you cannot.  OWIN middleware does not designed to do that.  It is independent of the application.

If you want a custom 404 error page, you can add a setting in the web.config file to do this for you:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <error statusCode="404" path="/somedir/oops404.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDotKnox. So from what you are saying I would imply that the middleware is totally independent of the ASP.NET MVC architecture. It does not know of the context in which it is running. So If I want to only have acceptable routes and everything else directed to somewhere else I would either use a custom error page in the web config or do a "catch all" route in the routing table and direct it to a controller action of my choosing. Correct?

Comment: @AranMulholland  Correct.  OWIN is just a pipeline to ASP.net and the middleware knows nothing about what is at the end of the pipeline.  And likewise, ASP.net knows nothing about what middleware might be running before or after it.  That's what makes OWIN so cool and powerful.  It is completely independent of the application and the server.

Comment: You do have the Owin Context though, is this different depending on what server infrastructure you are running on? It seems to have information relating to asp.net when that is your server infrastructure. I'll have another look but I seem to remember stuff that looked like it was asp.net related.

Comment: It is, but you don't need to use the OwinContext object.  What the middleware receives is actually a Dictionary<string, object>

Comment: I have the same question, but with a console-hosted OWIN app. Do you know what the equivalent solution is?

Comment: @ZachSmith You could write a custom middleware to do that and get a list of endpoints using reflection during initialization.  It would be easier if you were using attribute routing.